# Getting nil when calling [NSBundle pathForResource] (Localization Issue)

Tags: macos, cocoa, localization, osx-snow-leopard, nsbundle

I localized a text file in my application that currently is only supported in English
[image]

I'm using this code to get the path:

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Quotes" ofType:@"txt"]
```

On my system (Lion 10.7.2) it returns the expected path (English) when on any language

> build/Beta/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Quotes.txt

But for some international users, this code is returning nil.
I have not yet confirmed it but currently its only happened to Snow Leopard users.

Any Ideas?
Thank you.

Edit:

- Mac OSX 10.7.2 German
- Snow Leopard   English
- Mac 10.6.8     German
- Mac OSX 10.7.2 Chinese

Snow leopard theory is gone also, there is an English mac that also returns nil, this is confusing.

Comment: Have you tried + (NSBundle *)bundleWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier method?

Comment: Do you mean to check if its returning the correct bundle?

Answer (score 1):

I got it, I have a workspace including ios & mac projects both sharing this file. But the ios version has the value "en" on Localization native development Region key in info.plist and the Mac has "English" I changed the Mac project to "en" and updated all the localized files.

Users that did not have "English" in their list language on System Preference -> Language & Text where getting nil.

Credit goes to Ken Thomases from the Apple Forums